# Countdown for word game using C++

Tags: c++, timer

I have this word game and I want it to run for some time using a timer. I don't know how to both run the timer and the game simultaneously. I also want to show the timer countdown in the console along the game.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Typically you would poll the state of the game every *x* milliseconds, and update the console based on that.  The state of the game would include the current time, the game board, etc.  User input would be polled in a similar way instead of blocking on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your game within the while loop below. This app stops after 10 seconds (roughly).

```cpp
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  struct timespec ts;
  clockid_t clock = CLOCK_REALTIME;

  if (clock_gettime(clock, &ts) == -1) {
    cerr << "Failed to get clock" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  long endTime = ts.tv_sec + 10;

  while (endTime > ts.tv_sec) {
    cout << "This app will stop soon" << endl;
    sleep(1);
    if (clock_gettime(clock, &ts) == -1) {
      cerr << "Failed to get clock" << endl;
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```